# css divs have different widths when they shouldnt

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a div container that contains 2 divs: banner and content. Both banner and content have css property width set to 100% but they are different when rendered.

this is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>JoeY34kaze's gw2 stuff</title>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>
                This is my header.
            </h1>
        </header>
        <div id="banner">
            <h2>
                This is the banner.
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my style.css

```
    body {
    text-align:center;
}


header {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    z-index:10;
    position: fixed;
}

#container {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:100%;
    padding:0;
}

#banner {
    width:100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding:0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    background-color:#707070;
}

#content {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    top:400px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

and the page looks like this:

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abbu2.png)

Until i resolve this issue the page is also live here https://gw2stuff.herokuapp.com/

The problem is that on the right side the 2 divs aren't aligned, but they should be.
I think that the problem comes from the relative position of the content div, but i was unable to fix it, so my question is how do i align the 2 divs so that their widths will match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the default `margin` on the `body`

```
body {
margin:0;
}
```

The `#content` div is affected by that margin but the fixed position elements are not although they are *placed* in relation to that margin becausee you have not stated a `left:0` position for them.

This should be automatically included in any CSS Reset.

Comment: This is your solution, Paulie beat me to it :-)

Answer (score -1):

Add`margin: 0` to the *content*,
If this doesn't work, move the content a little, perhaps `left: 5px` would work

Comment: i tried that when i was solving myself and it didn't work. Adding margin:0 to body is the solution though.

Answer (score -1):

Change position of `content` to:

```
 position: fixed;
```

Comment: although that would solve the issue, i don't want the content to be fixed.